# Looping over querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, while-loop, jquery-selectors

i'm trying to put my queryselectorall clicks inside of a loop, so i dont have to do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class a')[1].click();
document.querySelectorAll('.class a')[2].click();
document.querySelectorAll('.class a')[3].click();
```

I wanted to make a while until the index is 47, i try to make it like this

```
var class = document.querySelectorAll('.class a');
var i;
while (i < 47){
 class[i].click();
 i++;
}
```

But is not working.

Comment: `class` is a very bad name for a variable. Use a different one. If you look into the console, JS tells you exactly that ...

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How is it not working?

Comment: Also initialize `i` or else that while condition is false to begin with

Comment: I'm not actually using class as a name for the variable, it was just an examble; i initilalized the i = 0; but it dosn't work.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, the scripts just stops

Comment: @antonellamanzur solved check here https://jsfiddle.net/0zquL1e3/7/

Answer (score 1):

For starters you never initialize your `i` variable to 0, so when you start your loop, `i` is equal to `undefined`. Next, you need to change your variable name. `class` is a reserved word just like `function`. Also if you want the index to go to index 47 you would need to do `i < 48` or `i <= 47`, otherwise the loop will stop at index 46. That being said, it would be better if you used the length of the query so you only went for as many elements as your querySelectorAll() points to. Otherwise, if the number of elements the selector points to changes in your HTML, you will have to remember to go in and change the hardcoded number in your loop or there will be issues. Much better to cache the length in another local variable right after declaring the variable.

Try this:

```
var classAPointer = document.querySelectorAll('.class a'),
    numClassAElements = classAPointer.length,
    i = 0;

for (; i < numClassAElements; ++i) {
  classAPointer[i].click();
}
```

You may be interested in reading this post regarding different ways to loop over a querySelectorAll NodeList: https://css-tricks.com/a-bunch-of-options-for-looping-over-queryselectorall-nodelists/ (The most performant methods are either regular for loops like above or using a for... of loop, which you should only do if you don't care about supporting IE or legacy browsers)

Comment: I just did that, but is still not working

Comment: "Not working" is not a helpful comment. Please provide console errors or some kind of other indication of what is going on. If you cannot or do not know how to provide more debugging information, then please edit your question to include more of your code. Check my answer again because I have edited it since I first posted. Unless I made a typo I don't see the problem is most likely elsewhere in your code.

Comment: i'm not getting any errors, the script just stops and it doesn't show any of the elements inside the queryselector.

Comment: Have you seen my most recent edit to this answer? If you have and it still does not work please edit your question to include more code.

What do you mean by it not showing any elements inside your queryselector? Do you mean that it is not selecting any elements from the DOM? Try doing a quick `console.log(classAPointer)` before the loop and then check the console and make sure it is logging a nodelist with all your elements in it. If it isn't then the problem is your argument you are passing to `querySelectorAll`. `.class a` selects `<a>` elements that are children of .class class elements